# Laptop Internal Mic not working Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: sound, microphone

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on a HP Pavilion dv6 laptop.  My laptop's mic is detected, but does not pick up any sound.  When I mute and then unmute it, a faint pop can be recorded by it, but the mic then gets no more info.  I have set my audio profile in PulseAudio Volume Control (pavucontrol) to Analog Stereo Duplex.  I have tested and confirmed that the external mic port can record sound using my headphones as a microphone.

---

I found out that my mic is broken, there is not an Ubuntu problem.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Install `pavucontrol` package and try to enable it there.

Comment: I already have pavucontrol installed, this is where I change my settings.  I am unable to get my mic to get any input other than when I unmute it.